# How to create an Action<T> form an object method given via Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, lambda

I have a `void SubscribeToPublish<TMessage>(Action<TMessage> action)` method. And it expects an `Action<T>`. I have an object created purely from `Type` in a way like this:

```
var Node =  Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public).Where(methodInfo => methodInfo.GetParameters().Count() == 1).ToList();
methods.ForEach(methodInfo => {
    SubscribeToPublish(o => methodInfo.Invoke( pair.Value.Node, o )); // Here I see error cannot be inferred from usage.
});
```

Thus I wonder: how to create `Action<T>` on the go having objects created via Reflection?

Comment: can you provide error message and stack trace?

Comment: Your error is happen in compile time or run? I guess you should use (TMessage msg) => methodInfo.Invoke(pair.Value.Node, msg)

Comment: Does it have to be via reflection? What about Linq Expression compilation?

Comment: BTW. Given you are checking for `methodInfo.GetParameters().Count() == 1` the delegate MUST be of `Action<T1, T2>`, as you need both the object you are calling on and the parameter to the method.

Answer (score 4):

`methodInfo.Invoke` accepts arbitrary object parameters. Thus, the compiler cannot infer which concrete `TMessage` type you mean.

The solution is to specify it explicitly:

```
SubscribeToPublish((MyMessage o) => methodInfo.Invoke(pair.Value.Node, 
                                                      new object[] {o}));
```

Comment: or `SubscribeToPublish<MyMessage>(o=>...)` :-)

Comment: The main problem is that object type is unknown for the method we are dinamically invoking=(

Comment: @DuckQueen: In that case, `SubscribeToPublish((object o) => ...)` would be an option, if `SubscribeToPublish`'s logic does not depend on the actual type of `TMessage`.

Comment: And the next problem is that it does=(

Comment: @DuckQueen: Then generics are the wrong solution to the problem. Generic information is *statically* typed, i.e., it needs to be known at *compile time*. For your problem, a non-generic method that does a *run-time type check* might be better suited.